# Mac OS 10.8 Quick look style window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am new at Mac and iOS software development, and I was wondering if there is a way to use the 
Mac OS 10.8 Quick look window style. It isn't an option in interface builder, so is there any way to do it by code?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at these:

[QuickLookDownloader](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/QuickLookDownloader/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009082-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)
[QuickLook Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Since the question is about a window **style**, I assume it is not about using an actual Quick Look window.